# Entity Framework performance of partial model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server DB with over 500 tables. Some of the tables are *large* (over 1 billion rows). Most of the tables are *small*. (Under 1 million rows.)

I have a partial EF model which maps about 25 tables, all of which are *small*. In general, when I want to use EF with another table, I simply add it to the model, but this now has me wondering a couple of things:

1. If I were to map the entire DB, but only actually use about 25 tables, would there be any noticeable difference in performance when compared to limiting the model size by including only the required tables? (I'm guessing the generated queries would be the same, so I suppose only the memory footprint might be different, but is this negligible?)
2. Some of the tables that I include in the model have FKs to some of the *large* tables which are not (currently) included in the model. If I added those large tables to the model, could this have any effect on performance due to the FK, or otherwise? (I assume the DB does the same FK verification regardless of whether EF knows about it or not. So my question is more if EF does anything extra regarding FKs which could affect performance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of rows in tables you map into EF model is completely irrelevant I think, whether it has billion rows or zero. Then, if you add more tables to your model, it might increase time it will take to parse and load model into memory, but that is negligible and only happens once, so I think you can completely ignore that.

About foreign keys - unless you will load related entities or do Includes, I doubt EF will do anything extra in regard to those keys.

In short, I think you can safely add all tables without any noticeable perfomance loss. Note however that this will bloat your model and your intellisense quite a bit, so better not do it unless necessary.

Comment: I agree. The only possible hazard is triggering lazy loading of navigation properties pointing to *large* tables and also containing a considerable subset of it.

Comment: @Evk - good point regarding intellisense. In our case much of our non-EF objects have similar names, so this would be an annoying side effect of unnecessarily bringing in all tables.